# Selected Item WPF DataGrid With Selection Mode Extended

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I have an application that uses mvvm which has a DataGrid with SelectionMode set to Extended.  I have two buttons "Move Up" and "Move Down" which when clicked are supposed to move the position of the selected item up or down one spot (only if only one item is selected).

This works fine (code to follow), however, after performing a move, it appears to break the selected item trigger.  For example, if I click an item, move it down 4 spots, click another item and try to move it up a spot, the previously moved item will become selected again and move.  A breakpoint set on "SelectItem" in the VM stops being hit, even after clearing all selections and selecting an entirely new row.  This issue does not happen if selection mode is set to Single.

I have tried enabling and disabling virtualization, IsSynchronisedWIthCurrentItem, different list types, etc, nothing changes this behavior.  I am pulling my hair out.  Can anyone suggest a way around this?

My Grid and buttons...

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Button Margin="3" Content="Move Up">
                    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                            <ei:CallMethodAction TargetObject="{Binding}"
                                                 MethodName="MoveUp" />
                        </i:EventTrigger>
                    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                </Button>
                <Button Margin="3" Content="Move Down">
                    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                            <ei:CallMethodAction TargetObject="{Binding}"
                                                 MethodName="MoveDown" />
                        </i:EventTrigger>
                    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                </Button>
            </StackPanel>

            <DataGrid Margin="3"
                      x:Name="DataGrid"
                      AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Items, Mode=OneWay}"
                      SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}"
                      CanUserAddRows="False"
                      CanUserDeleteRows="False"
                      IsReadOnly="True"
                      SelectionMode="Extended">
                    <DataGrid.RowStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
                        <Setter Property="IsSelected"
                                Value="{Binding Path=IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                    </Style>
                </DataGrid.RowStyle>

                <DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <CheckBox Margin="3"
                                      IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}}}"
                                      IsTabStop="False" />
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>
            </DataGrid>
        </StackPanel>
```

My pertinent VM Code...

```
public ObservableCollection<ListItemViewModelBase<Person>> Items
    {
        get { return _items ?? (_items = new ObservableCollection<ListItemViewModelBase<Person>>()); }
    }

    public ListItemViewModelBase<Person> SelectedItem
    {
        get { return _selectedItem; }
        set
        {
            if (_selectedItem == value)
                return;

            _selectedItem = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => SelectedItem);
        }
    } 

public void MoveUp()
    {
        if (Items.Count(item => item.IsSelected) == 1)
        {
            // get it's index
                int toMoveIndex = Items.IndexOf(SelectedItem);

                // move up if not at zero
                if (toMoveIndex > 0)
                {
                    Items.Move(toMoveIndex, toMoveIndex - 1);
                }
        }
    }

    public void MoveDown()
    {
        if (Items.Count(item => item.IsSelected) == 1)
        {
            // get it's index
                int toMoveIndex = Items.IndexOf(SelectedItem);

                // move down if not at zero
                if (toMoveIndex < Items.Count - 1)
                {
                    Items.Move(toMoveIndex, toMoveIndex + 1);
                }
        }
    }
```

And the Person and ListItemBase classes...

```
public class Person : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnProperyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    #endregion

    #region Fields

    private string _firstName;
    private Guid _id;
    private string _lastName;
    private int _sortOrder;

    public int SortOrder
    {
        get { return _sortOrder; }
        set
        {
            if (_sortOrder == value)
                return;

            _sortOrder = value;
            OnProperyChanged("SortOrder");
        }
    }

    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return _firstName; }
        set
        {
            if (_firstName == value)
                return;

            _firstName = value;
            OnProperyChanged("FirstName");
        }
    }

    public string LastName
    {
        get { return _lastName; }
        set
        {
            if (_lastName == value)
                return;

            _lastName = value;
            OnProperyChanged("LastName");
        }
    }

    public Guid Id
    {
        get { return _id; }
        set
        {
            if (_id == value)
                return;

            _id = value;
            OnProperyChanged("Id");
        }
    }

    public static bool operator ==(Person item1, Person item2)
    {
        // if both null, equal
        if (ReferenceEquals(item1, null) && ReferenceEquals(item2, null))
            return true;

        // if one null, one not, not equal
        if (!ReferenceEquals(item1, null) && ReferenceEquals(item2, null))
            return false;

        if (ReferenceEquals(item1, null))
            return false;

        return item1.Equals(item2);
    }

    public static bool operator !=(Person item1, Person item2)
    {
        return !(item1 == item2);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("{0} {1}: {2}", FirstName, LastName, SortOrder);
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        var item = obj as Person;

        if (item != null)
        {
            return Equals(item);
        }

        return base.Equals(obj);
    }

    public bool Equals(Person item)
    {
        if (item != null)
        {
            return GetHashCode() == item.GetHashCode();
        }

        return false;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Id.GetHashCode();
    }
}

public class ListItemViewModelBase<TModel> : ViewModelBaseExtended, IEquatable<ListItemViewModelBase<TModel>>
{
    private bool _isSelected;
    private TModel _model;

    public ListItemViewModelBase(TModel model)
    {
        if (model == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("model", "The model cannot be null.");
        }

        // set initial values
        Model = model;
    }

    public static bool operator ==(ListItemViewModelBase<TModel> item1, ListItemViewModelBase<TModel> item2)
    {
        // if both null, equal
        if (ReferenceEquals(item1, null) && ReferenceEquals(item2, null))
            return true;

        // if one null, one not, not equal
        if (!ReferenceEquals(item1, null) && ReferenceEquals(item2, null))
            return false;

        if (ReferenceEquals(item1, null))
            return false;

        return item1.Equals(item2);
    }

    /// <returns></returns>
    public static bool operator !=(ListItemViewModelBase<TModel> item1, ListItemViewModelBase<TModel> item2)
    {
        return !(item1 == item2);
    }

    public virtual bool IsSelected
    {
        get { return _isSelected; }
        set { Set(() => IsSelected, ref _isSelected, value); }
    }

    public TModel Model
    {
        get { return _model; }
        set { Set(() => Model, ref _model, value); }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Model.ToString();
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Model.GetHashCode();
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        var item = obj as ListItemViewModelBase<TModel>;

        if (item != null)
            return Equals(item);

        return base.Equals(obj);
    }

    public bool Equals(ListItemViewModelBase<TModel> other)
    {
        if (other != null)
        {
            // use Equals() here, not == because it's a Generic, == won't work
            return Model.Equals(other.Model);
        }

        return false;
    }

    }
```

Any insights would be greatly appreciated.  I am going bananas trying to work around this.  I have seen the same results with ListBox, ListView, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found a "solution".  I hate it, because it seems to fly in the face of the binding engine that makes WPF so attractive, but's the only thing that I've found that will work. Basically, I have to create a temp list, re-order it, clear my observable collection and re=populate it...

```
public void MoveUp()
        {
            if (Items.Count(item => item.IsSelected) == 1)
            {
                // create a list with the current items
                var items = new List<ListItemViewModelBase<Person>>(Items);
                // get the index of the item being moved
                int oldIndex = items.IndexOf(SelectedItem);

                // only move if the item isn't already at 0
                if (oldIndex > 0)
                {
                    // get the item we're moving
                    var item = items[oldIndex];
                    // remove the item from the list
                    items.RemoveAt(oldIndex);
                    // add the item back into the list at it's new position
                    items.Insert(oldIndex - 1, item);

                    // clear items list, and re-add items from our temp list
                    Items.Clear();
                    foreach (var toAdd in items)
                    {
                        Items.Add(toAdd);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public void MoveDown()
        {
            if (Items.Count(item => item.IsSelected) == 1)
            {
                // create a list with the current items
                var items = new List<ListItemViewModelBase<Person>>(Items);
                // get the index of the item being moved
                int oldIndex = items.IndexOf(SelectedItem);

                // only move if the item isn't already the last item
                if (oldIndex < items.Count - 1)
                {
                    // get the item we're moving
                    var item = items[oldIndex];
                    // remove the item from the list
                    items.RemoveAt(oldIndex);
                    // add the item back into the list at it's new position
                    items.Insert(oldIndex + 1, item);

                    // clear items list, and re-add items from our temp list
                    Items.Clear();
                    foreach (var toAdd in items)
                    {
                        Items.Add(toAdd);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

If anyone has a better idea, I am still very open to hearing it!

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered such error too, unfortunately i have no answer on how to properly avoid this problem, though i can add few details.

First - problem about multiple selection of old moved items has place only when 4.5 Framework is installed in system, though application targets 4.0.

Second- There were some fixes by Microsoft related to selection in DataGrid:

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/565153/wpf-datagrid-vs2010-net-4-0-datagrid-selecteditem-isenabled-bug

Looks like it was fixed in 4.5 what led to another post:

http://www.beta.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/742545/net-4-5-changes-4-0-wpf-datagrid-behaviour

Maybe those fixes led to a new bugs.

As for me i came up to similar workaround as you, but i am not creating a new temporary list, but use

```
ListViewAudio.RemoveAt(oldIndex);
ListViewAudio.Insert(newIndex, selectedItem);
```

on my List instead of

```
ListViewAudio.Move(oldIndex, newIndex);
```

My new behavior along with yours behavior with new temporary list leads to another bug. If i use MoveUp on the last item in list or MoveDown for the first in list, they get moved and loose selection. Are you experiencing the same problem?

Comment: I don't have that problem.  Maybe due to my temp list and recreation?

Comment: I tried creating a temporary List, still have problem, though now(with temporary list) problem reproduces only for MoveUp from last entry.